# Установка Linux-дистрибутива на соседний диск рядом с Windows

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, ос

Я бы хотел спросить, насколько хороша идея установить на диск D операционную систему линукс, в то время как на диске C стоит винда, и могу ли я оставить все программы и файлы на диске D куда я установлю линукс, и будет ли иметь доступ виндоус к файлам с диска D (и наоборот)?

Comment: Из Windows [разбейте диск D на два раздела](https://www.dmosk.ru/instruktions.php?object=diskpart), после чего устанавливайте Linux в пустой раздел, образовавшийся после разбиения. И не забудьте сделать копию всех данных с D: на случай выбора не того раздела в установщике.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Тут несколько вопросов в одном. Короткие ответы: 1. да, можно поставить на соседний диск Linux-дистрибутив, но заранее необходимо подготовить место и необходимые разделы. Linux-дистрибутив будет видеть все файлы Windows, но наоборот нет (хотя тут многое зависит от настроек. Вроде бы в последних обновах такое уже можно, но вопрос не изучал ещё.)

Comment: Можно, но обычно не нужно. Для каких целей вам нужен линукс?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко какая разница для чего человеку нужна данная система? *Можно, но обычно не нужно.* - поясните...? О_о

Comment: @Иван лучше добавить в тело вопроса также информацию о том, какой Windows установлен, сколько места для манипуляций с диском доступно, а также какой дистрибутив Linux планируется установить?!

Comment: @L.F.C часто люди не догадываются о наличии других вариантов. К примеру для программирования под линукс, что актуально на этом сайте, в большинстве случаев сильно удобнее настроить wsl, чем ставить вторую систему и постоянно туда сюда переключаться.

Comment: @L,F.C "заранее необходимо подготовить место" - Не всегда. Приличные инсталляторы, до начала установки Linux, говорят о том, что обнаружена другая ОС и предлагают подкорректировать таблицу разделов.  Насколько такой вариант безопасен - решать надо самому. Но, когда я последний раз ставил бубунту, всё прошло гладко. Винду инсталятор ужал, а на осовободившееся место установил люних.